# Implementation of MD5 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, bit

I was following a page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Pseudocode) about the implementation of MD5. The pseudocode is directly embedded in the link.

However, while I was translating the pseudocode into python, it gives a pretty weird output that has nothing similar to the one shown in the demo.

**md5.py**

```py
import math


def leftrotate(x, c):
    return (x << c) or (x >> (32 - c))


# All variables are unsigned 32 bit and wrap modulo 2^32 when calculating
s = [None] * 64
K = [None] * 64

# s specifies the per-round shift amounts
s[0:16] = [7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22]
s[16:32] = [5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20, 5, 9, 14, 20]
s[32:48] = [4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23]
s[48:64] = [6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21]

# Use binary integer part of the sines of integers (Radians) as constants:
K = [math.floor(math.pow(2, 32) * math.fabs(math.sin(i + 1))) for i in range(64)]

# Initialize variables
a0 = 0x67452301
b0 = 0xefcdab89
c0 = 0x98badcfe
d0 = 0x10325476

msg0 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
# Converting String to binary
msg = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in msg0)

# Pre-processing: adding a single bit
#   The input bytes are considered as bits strings,
#   where the first bit is the most significant bit of the byte
message = list(msg)
message.append("1")

# Pre-processing: padding with zeros
for i in range(447 - len(msg)):
    message.append("0")
for i in range(64):
    message.append("64")

msg = "".join(message)

M = []
for i in range(0, 512, 32):
    M.append("".join(message[i:i + 32]))
# Initialize hash value for this chunk
A = a0
B = b0
C = c0
D = d0

for i in range(64):
    F = 0
    g = 0
    if 0 <= i <= 15:
        F = D ^ (B and (C ^ D))
        g = i
    elif 16 <= i <= 31:
        F = C ^ (D and (B ^ C))
        g = (5 * i + 1) % 16
    elif 32 <= i <= 47:
        F = B ^ C ^ D
        g = (3 * i + 5) % 16
    elif 48 <= i <= 63:
        F = C ^ (B or (not D))
        g = (7 * i) % 16
    # Be wary of the below definitions of a, b, c, d
    F = F + A + K[i] + int(M[g])
    A = D
    D = C
    C = B
    B = B + leftrotate(F, s[i])

a0 += A
b0 += B
c0 += C
d0 += D

print(a0 + b0 + c0 + d0)
```

**output**

```
(input = msg0 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
64753135551430969455044517516606091785810184138594829859667366632969211689605539951611300227364936455768076694404884226395355419
03996976374438250472707827439981815374596773986313857734975864212023704601385676211761628136173288119161166663698645808505752643
4
```

In detail, may somebody please explain this line to me:

> break chunk into sixteen 32-bit words `M[j]`, 0 ≤ j ≤ 15

I was pretty confused at this point, having believed that the `message` should be inputted as a string but converting it to binary doesn't work. I thought that, on the page, the phrase *bit* means *binary* or am I wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you think "binary" means? Because a "bit" is a single digit in binary data ("bit" is short for "Binary digIT"), but they're not synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First obvious error:

```
K = [math.floor(math.pow(2, 32) * math.fabs(math.sin(i + 1))) for i in range(63)]
```

The pseudo-code is using inclusive bounds notation; `range` is exclusive on the upper bound, so you just made a `K` that is 63 elements long, when it's supposed to be 64 elements long.

Same issue with your final loop:

```
for i in range(63):
```

Probably ought to check your other bounds to make sure you haven't made similar errors elsewhere.

This is also dead wrong:

```
msg = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in msg0)
```

because it doesn't pad the input bytes the way it should, so your bits are all a jumble. There's a lot of ways to do this (you could probably make it work with a format string of `'08b'` assuming all your characters have ordinal values below 256, though it's a rather inefficient solution).

Also wrong:

```
for i in range(64):
    message.append("64")
```

You're supposed to append the original length in bits mod `2**64`, not the *number* 64 repeated 64 times (I have no idea where you came up with that).

For your final question, to explain "break chunk into sixteen 32-bit words M[j], 0 ≤ j ≤ 15", "32 bit words" means "integers comprised of 32 binary bits". For a simple example, breaking `0b100100001111` into three four bit words would produce `0b1001, 0b0000, 0b1111`.

Unfortunately for you, in Python, `int`s are infinite precision; they don't drop overflowing bits when a computation produces a result with more than 32 bits, and MD5 calculations assume they do. So you're going to need to simulate it with a lot of masking, by bitwise and-ing via `& 0xffffffff`.

In short **implementing MD5 in plain Python from the pseudocode is a royal pain in the butt, because the pseudocode *relies* on the limitations of a low level language like C**. And you're clearly not being careful enough implementing even the bits that do translate naturally to Python.

Comment: Should I still convert the initial input to an array, then?

Comment: @cpy24: You didn't convert anything to an array, you made a Python `list` (the distinction is going to be important, keep reading). I'd suggest looking at the Python modules that give you access to C-like data types, e.g. `array` (which unlike `list`, actually stores raw C level data types), `struct` and/or `ctypes`, to let you simulate the limitations of C in Python.